# Changing the NBT data of a variable amount of items in a chest inventory?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

My goal is to be able to put a variable amount of gold nuggets in a chest and then run some commands to replace those with gold nuggets that have edited display NBT data.

Is this even possible? I'm encountering a few issues.

First, when checking for the amount of gold nuggets in an inventory with **/testforblock**, I have to specify the amount of gold nuggets I am testing for. However, I want the amount of nuggets you input to be variable, not restricted to a certain stack size. I also want it to be able to work with every slot in the chest, so somebody can fill the whole thing up.

Second, how would I store the amount of nuggets being inputted into the chest and pass that value to **/replaceitem** so that I replace the correct number of gold nuggets with edited display NBT nuggets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first problem, you don't have to specify a slot or count when testing for NBT data. Try something like this:

```
/testforblock X Y Z chest -1 {Items:[{id:minecraft:gold_nugget}]}
```

That way, the command will succeed if any gold nuggets are in any slot.

---

No good way to do the second problem, AFAIK. Best way would be do:

1. Break the chest with a `/setblock`
2. Identify the golden nugget items that just dropped with a scoreboard objective, E.G: `/scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] isNugget 1 {Item:{id:minecraft:gold_nugget}}`
3. Change the NBT data of the dropped nuggets: `/entitydata @e[type=Item,score_IsNugget_min=1] {Item:{tag:{display:{Name:"NUGGET"}}}}`
4. Use a (minecart) hopper to scoop the items back up into a chest.

Comment: For the second problem, you could use the /blockdata command to set a display tag, although this would require a different command for each slot in the chest, so it would be annoying to set up.

Comment: @Silentvenom7 A different command for each slot, and for each potential item amount; I don't think 1728 command blocks is worth it.

Comment: couldn't you just omit the Count tag? Or does that not work when assigning data?

Comment: @Silentvenom7 When changing items in an inventory I think you have to the entire item.