# How to lock items into inventory/chest slots using NBT data in Java Edition?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

It's a bit like [Changing the NBT data of a variable amount of items in a chest inventory?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/235468/changing-the-nbt-data-of-a-variable-amount-of-items-in-a-chest-inventory) but I want to do it using NBT data (like possible in Bedrock Edition) and without the need to set up a repeating command block (I want a single-time command that gives an item with those properties). Is that even possible? If that's not possible it'll be okay, I can live without it ;) just would be nice to have.